# Mouseenter on 2 different pictures

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

For my questions I provide you with this fiddle I created:
http://jsfiddle.net/6x96w/

If you hover over the first person you can see that a black box hovers over the person, but the black box also hovers over the person below. I am trying to make the black box only appear on the first person and disappear when I move the mouse over it. Then when I hover on person no.2 the black box should only hover on that person.

So in short, I want the black box only to appear on the person I am hovering over.

Is this doable without creating extra long code of having different class for each person ?

The code for the function as it stands now is:

```
        $('.Claus').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.clickMe').fadeIn(500);      
        });
        $('.clickMe').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
        });
```

.clickMe has a default CSS of

```
       display:none
```

I can see that .clickMe of course triggers fadeIn when I mouseenter on .Claus which is triggering on the person below too. (I have over 20 persons I need this to work on, but I thought making 2 for this case would be sufficient)

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('img').not('.clickMe').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).prev('.clickMe').fadeIn(500);       
});
 $('.clickMe').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: Hi @user3003216 - That will definitely work, then I can just put comma between each persons I have. Sounds simple enough!

I see that I got a lot of other interesting answers so I'll upvote them. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Check out my edited answer, you don't need to specify the person name.. I misread your question, I think it's just 2 people.. ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do this for more than 1 or 2 persons, you should make a function that can be reused, I've made a simple example for you as the following:

```
$('.hoverable').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.clickMe').fadeIn(500);
});
```

it finds an element with the class `hoverable` and tries to find an element with the class `clickMe` inside the parent element of your `hoverable` element.

Now all you have to do is add the `hoverable` class to whichever person you want the effect to be on. 
Example of your jsFiddle:

```
<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dir/La9/dirLa9ri9.jpeg" class="Claus hoverable" />
```

It is also advisable to use an id instead of a class if you're looking for uniqueness like here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a generic listener for all elements with pictures

```
$('img').not('.clickMe').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.clickMe').fadeIn(500);
});
$('.clickMe').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/6x96w/2/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is pretty much what you want: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/6x96w/1/)

I have changed the seccond person to also be of the class "claus" (I dont understand why you would have one class for each person..)

I've also added this on claus mouse enter:

```
$(this).prev().fadeIn(500);
```

If you want one "claus" and one "david" then I guess you can make the same thing but for davids mouse-enter?